Is the Poisson bracket related to the Lie bracket of some Lie group?
A Lie algebra is a vector space $\mathcal{L}$ on which an operation called a Lie bracket, (denoted by $[. ,. ]$) is defined, which associates with a pair $X, Y\in \mathcal{L}$, the element $[X, Y]$ of $\mathcal{L}$ such that, for arbitrary vectors $X,Y,Z\in\mathcal{L}$ and arbitrary scalars $a, b$, we have

$[aX + bY, Z] = a[X, Z] + b[Y, Z]$  (linearity)

$[X, Y] = -[Y, X]$  (antisymmetry)

$[ [X, Y], Z] + [ [Y, Z], X] + [ [Z, X], Y] = 0$  (Jacobi identity)


A Lie group comes with a Lie algebra - the generators span a vector space and satisfy a Lie algebra. The most familiar example to physics students is the Lie algebra of $SU(2)$: $[T_a,T_b]=i\varepsilon_{abc}T_c$.
Is the converse true? Does a Lie algebra always give rise to generators and a Lie group? I have in mind the particular case of Hamiltonian mechanics. The tangent space of the $2n$-dimensional phase space is a $2n$-dimensional vector space with a Lie bracket $[.,.]$ given by the Poisson bracket, $\left[.,.\right]_{\rm PB}$:
$$
\left[f,g\right]_{\rm PB}\equiv \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\left[\frac{\partial f}{\partial q_i}\frac{\partial g}{\partial p_i}-\frac{\partial f}{\partial p_i}\frac{\partial g}{\partial q_i}\right].
$$
Does this involve a Lie group anywhere? I believe no. But I am not sure. [I know a little bit about the symplectic group. But I think this has nothing to do with the question I am asking.]
I'd appreciate it if the mathematics and mathematical notation remain simple.

Linked

Superalgebras are Lie algebras but there’s no group that I know of associated with these.

Linked.

Considering my mathematical exposure, I need some time to appreciate the answers. I wish to re-read the answers in the weekend. Hope you understand.

Since you asked for minimal mathematese, I'll provide the  elementary low-tech version, illustrated on a minimal 2-dimensional flat phase space. The Lie Group involved is a subgroup of the celebrated infinite-dimensional one of area preserving diffeomorphisms.  The infinity of its generators  is realized by
$$
_=\partial_x f~ \partial_p - \partial_p f~~ \partial_x
$$
for an infinity of arbitrary f(x,p).
Exponentiate to get the group elements,
$$
e^{\partial_x f~ \partial_p - \partial_p f~~ \partial_x},
$$
Work out the commutators, in your language,
$$
[T_A,T_B]= T_{\{A,B\} }.
$$
The generator $T_f$ transforms (x, p) to
$(x − ∂f /∂p , p + ∂ f /∂x)$. Infinitesimally, this is a canonical transformation generated
by f, which preserves the phase-space area element dxdp. (This element is referred to as a symplectic form and the class of transformations that leaves it invariant specifies a symplectic geometry.) You may regard it as the flow generated by an arbitrary "hamiltonian" f.
There is a groaning literature on the associated gauge theories, commonly  labelled by $SU(\infty)$. For more information, here is an ancient overview talk of mine.
The extension to multi-dimensional phase space is straightforward through the introduction of gradients (symplectic ones).

This isn’t really right. Especially regarding the topology and groups involved. Firstly, it is not $C^{\infty}(M)$ which gets exponentiated, it is $C^{\infty}(M)/\Bbb{R}$ (assuming $M$ is connected) which gets exponentiated. Next, when you exponentiate you only get a certain subgroup $\mathcal{H}$ of the symplectic-isomorphisms/area-preserving diffeomorphisms $\mathcal{S}$. In particular for the torus $T^2$, we get a strict subgroup (in fact the quotient is $\mathcal{S}/\mathcal{H}\cong H^1(\Bbb{T}^2;\Bbb{R})/H^1(\Bbb{T}^2;\Bbb{Z})\cong \Bbb{T}^2$). See chapter 10 of McDuff for details.

These caveats hold even in the special case of  $\dim M=2$ as I mentioned above. Of course, you could bypass all these topological caveats but you should really mention from the beginning you’re considering only $\Bbb{R}^2$ (or $\Bbb{R}^{2n}$). Or change the second sentence “is the celebrated…” to “is a subgroup of…”

The OP asked for a math-light version, which I illustrated on freshman physics flat phase space. Beyond my ancient talk which fusses some topologies, torus, etc, the OP may track the limits down. There was lots of drivel floating around 35 yrs ago…

Wanting to not go into technicalities is perfectly fine. I perfectly agree with that stance; I didn’t give the proofs of the last few claims in my answer either. But you should atleast edit to have a correct statement (like you did now :) And ideally lest the reader confuse the special case for the general case, mention in your final paragraph that symplectic diffeomorphisms = area/volume-preserving diffeomorphisms only for 2-dimensions.

If a reader wished to follow up in the literature, surely they could generalize area past 2dim!  Or ask the question in MSE... I fear the focus of the question is not canonical transformations, normally restricted to trivial phase spaces.


Does a Lie algebra always give rise to generators and a Lie group?

A Lie algebra is a vector space, and every vector space has a basis (obvious in finite dimensions; in infinite dimensions it’s more subtle and depends on what exactly you mean, but every infinite dimensional vector space has a Hamel basis - this is equivalent to the axiom of choice). Next, you want Lie’s third theorem.


The tangent space of the $2n$-dimensional phase space is a $2n$-dimensional vector space

True, but not relevant. Why not relevant? Because your next part of the sentence is wrong

with a Lie bracket $[.,.]$ given by the Poisson bracket

It is wrong in the sense that your phrasing makes it seem that it is a Poisson bracket on the $2n$-dimensional tangent spaces.

What we actually have (and this answers your title question in the affirmative modulo infinite-dimensional technicalities) is the following: for every smooth manifold $M$, the set $\text{Diff}(M)$ of all diffeomorphisms of $M$ forms a group. With suitable mathematical jumping jacks in the case of $\dim M\geq 1$ we can provide this group with the structure of an infinite-dimensional (Frechet-)Lie group. The Lie algebra of this Lie group is the infinite-dimensional vector space of all smooth vector fields $\mathfrak{X}(M)$, and the Lie bracket here is the usual Lie bracket of vector fields $[X,Y]$.
Next, specifically on a symplectic manifold $(M,\omega)$, there’s a very close relationship between smooth functions and vector fields. For each function $f\in C^{\infty}(M)$, there’s a vector field $X_f:=\omega^{\sharp}(df)$; this is pretty much the ‘symplectic gradient’, i.e you essentially ‘raises the index of $df$ using $\omega$’. Next, we have that the Poisson bracket as you’ve defined it in local coordinates actually extends globally, so $\{\cdot,\cdot\}$ is a Poisson bracket on the space of smooth functions $C^{\infty}(M)$ (which is infinite-dimensional if $\dim M\geq 1$), NOT on the $2n$-dimensional tangent spaces of $M$. The relationship between the Poisson bracket of $C^{\infty}(M)$ and the Lie bracket of $\mathfrak{X}(M)$ is given by the above correspondence of vector fields and functions, namely for all $f,g\in C^{\infty}(M)$, we have
\begin{align}
X_{\{f,g\}}&=[X_f,X_g].\tag{$*$}
\end{align}
Extra: Finally for completeness, since the definition of $X_f:=\omega^{\sharp}(df)$ involves one derivative of the function, namely $df$, it shows that the mapping $f\mapsto X_f$ is not injective. The kernel is the space $\mathcal{C}$ of locally constant functions; if $M$ is connected, this is just $\Bbb{R}$. So, we have that the quotient $C^{\infty}(M)/\mathcal{C}$ is isomorphic to the space $\mathfrak{h}(M,\omega)$ of all vector fields of the form $X_f$’s, called the space of Hamiltonian vector fields. By taking the time-1 flow of these vector fields (this certainly exists if we’re dealing with compact $M$) we get the space of so called Hamiltonian diffeomorphisms (a subgroup $\mathcal{H}(M,\omega)$ of symplectic isomorphisms)). So, we have $C^{\infty}(M)/\mathcal{C}\cong \mathfrak{h}(M,\omega)$, and the latter is the Lie algebra to the subgroup $\mathcal{H}(M,\omega)$ of the symplectic-isomorphisms. This is somewhat tersely written on nLab, Proposition 2.2. Anyway, these infinite-dimensional things are all very technical; but the important thing to remember is equation $(*)$, which very concretely relates the Poisson bracket to the Lie bracket.
